# Finding inhabitants in Lambda P

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

I found two examples in some lecture notes online and I can't follow their approach on the solution. Maybe someone can help.

First they translate from predicate logic to $\lambda$P and then they give an inhabitant of the term. This is what is written in the lecture notes:

An inhabitant of the term $ (\Pi x :\text{Terms}.\text{P x}) \rightarrow (\text{P N}) $ is:
$$ \lambda p : (\Pi x : \text{Terms}. \text{P x}) . (\text{p N}) $$

And an inhabitant of the term $ \text{A} \rightarrow (\Pi x : \text{Terms}. \text{A})$ is:
$$ \lambda w: \text{A}. \lambda x : \text{Terms}.w $$

However, they didn't explain how they got the inhabitant. It would really help me understand the whole typing theory. Do they derive it via the typing rules? But than I still can't see what rule they would use. Or do you just have to see it?!

Thanks to who ever is helping me in advance!

Comment: Do you know how to prove the predicate logic analogues of these types?

Comment: @DerekElkins Yes, I believe I do. But I struggle to translate the whole proof to $\lambda$P. For example, I read that an implication introduction rule is the equivalent to an abstraction rule. But I don't see the equivalence. An implication introduction cancels an assumption. What part of the abstraction rule is this cancellation? Also, what is the equivalent to the start rule? I read, that a derivation in $lambda$P always begins with the start rule.

Comment: Hmmm, due to the fact, that the Type Inhabitation Problem is undecidable in $\lambda$P I tend to believe that my question is a rather difficult task to solve. Am I wrong?! That would mean 'you just have to see it' would be the answer to my question. Can anyone confirm?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a rule-by-rule correspondence between rules of natural deduction for first-order logic and the typing rules of $\lambda P$.<sup>1</sup> Here's a proof of the latter formula (written as $A\to\mathsf{Terms}\to A$ as $\Pi x:A.B$ where $x$ is not free in $B$ is usually taken as the *definition* of $A\to B$ in dependently typed contexts):
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{A,\mathsf{Terms}\vdash A}\rlap{\mathsf{Hyp}}}{A\vdash\mathsf{Terms}\to A}\rlap{\to I}}{\vdash A\to\mathsf{Terms}\to A}\rlap{\to I}$$
and here's is the corresponding typing derivation: $$\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{x:A,y:\mathsf{Terms}\vdash x: A}\rlap{\mathsf{Hyp}}}{x:A\vdash(\lambda y:\mathsf{Terms}.x):\mathsf{Terms}\to A}\rlap{\to I}}{\vdash (\lambda x:A.\lambda y:\mathsf{Terms}.x) :  A\to\mathsf{Terms}\to A}\rlap{\to I}$$

Finding a term of a given type is more or less equivalent to finding a proof of the corresponding formula. It no more (or less) requires needing to "just see it" than finding a proof does. Indeed, if we look for normal form terms then (assuming $A$ and $\mathsf{Terms}$ are primitive types about which we know nothing) this is the only normal form lambda term of this type and it is completely mechanically derivable from the type. In general, though, finding a term, like finding a proof, is hard. Both of these problems<sup>2</sup> are semidecidable. If you have a proof though, producing the corresponding lambda term is a straightforward mechanical task.

<sup>1</sup> Okay, $\lambda P$ corresponds more to a first-order logic where you can quantify over functions.

<sup>2</sup> As indicated, they are really the same problem.

Comment: I learnt that every derivation in $\lambda$P has to start with the axiom $\emptyset \vdash \ast : \square$, where $\ast$ represents data-types and propositions and $\square$ represents kinds. Why is that not the case in the solution you gave?

Comment: However, after many tries, I came up with the axiom $\emptyset \vdash \ast : \square$ when I assume $A$ and Terms to be data-types, so:   $\text{Terms}:\ast , A:\ast \vdash (\lambda x : A. \lambda y : \text{Terms}.x) : A \rightarrow \text{Terms} \rightarrow A$ . But can I always assume that?!   P.S.: My derivation involves multiple uses of the abstraction rule, the product rule, the weakening rule and the start rule.

Comment: I did omit extra premises that check whether the types are well formed. Basically, each use of $\to I$ will have an extra $\Gamma\vdash(\Pi x:A.B(x)):*$ premise that will need to be derived. Producing derivations of these type well-formedness conditions is generally completely mechanical. Indeed, once you have the lambda term, producing the whole derivation is mechanical. This is why it suffices to provide just the lambda term in languages like Agda. This property is not true for all typed lambda calculi though.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. Thank you for clarification and the help.